# React Native - Login with Apple requestedScopes Not coming in Login PopUp for the name and email

Tags: ios, react-native, apple-login

HI i am trying to login with Apple.

I had added capabilities in Apple Signing. Here is my code

```
const loginApple = async () => {
const appleAuthRequestResponse = await appleAuth.performRequest({
  requestedOperation: appleAuth.Operation.LOGIN,
  requestedScopes: [appleAuth.Scope.EMAIL, appleAuth.Scope.FULL_NAME],
})
const { identityToken, nonce } = appleAuthRequestResponse
```

}

When I run on the iPhone. It just shows the Continue button. **Not a EMAIL and FULL_NAME**.

Why its not taking requestedScopes. I know that user will give the permission for the EMAIL and Name. But at lease it should show on the UI of Apple Pop Up for the Users to select permission.